# Android Navigation Drawer, Fragments, DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-dialogfragment, android-navigation

I am lost at how to implement this scenario:
I want to use `NavigationDrawer` for top-level switching. It will be something like this:

[image]

Fragments are used for all the Top Level Views and Lower Level Views.

This means I only have **One `Activity`**.

In the TopViews and LowerLevelViews, I may need the user to input something. I use variants of `Dialog`s which extends `DialogFragment`.

Under the normal coding pattern, one would define a listener interface in the `Dialog` which the `Activity` would implement.

Here comes my problem. I only have 1 activity and I have Three variants of `Dialog`. I have Three TopViews and Two LowerLevelViews in each TopViews. This brings me a total of Six (3 x 2) Fragment Views.

Any of the views can invoke a Dialog.

Currently my flow is this:

```
Fragment (view) needs to open Dialog -> Fragment informs Activity and remembers the Fragment -> Fragment instantiate the Dialog -> Dialog is presented
```

*After the user inputs and click OK.*

```
Dialog invokes the Activity's listener method -> Activity retrieve which Fragment initiated the Dialog -> Sends the value back to the Fragment.
```

How do I nicely send the value for the dialog to the correct view (fragment) since the `Dialog` only have access to the `Activity`?

Does the `Activity` HAVE TO control the flow? Because it is messy.

Not only that, within a `Fragment`, I have several `EditText` which invokes to `Dialog`. This means on top of keeping tab on which `Fragment` invoke the `Dialog` in the `Activity`, I also have to keep tab of which `EditText` within the `Fragment` invoke the `Dialog`.

Have I explained my issue well? Can someone suggest to me a better solution?

Comment: more long post nobody have time to read long post u have upload short problem what you want to do...that make easy to understand To make answer make good.

Comment: Why does your activity need to know about the dialogs? Fragments can just as easily be listeners can they not?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I do not think Fragments can be listeners because in the Dialog Fragment, I only have reference to the Activity. E.g. in my code
`builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.txtSave, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
 {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
  {
   AlertDialogListener activity = (AlertDialogListener) getActivity();
   activity.onFinishEditDialog(localEditText.getText().toString());
   dialog.dismiss();
...
`